# android animation while UI thread working

Tags: android, animation

My app has certain actions which require rendering a complicated layout. During that time, I'd like to show an animation. I'm trying to handle the animation in dispatchDraw(), but since the rendering is taking a long time the UI dispatchDraw() never gets a chance to execute. (It would be nice to optimize that but that isn't my priority right now.)

This is the essential part of my animation code:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat (1f, 2f);
animator.setDuration (1000);
animator.addUpdateListener (new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
{
  public void onAnimationUpdate (ValueAnimator animation)
  {
    zoomScale = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue ();
    invalidate ();
  }
});
```

Is there a way to draw directly during the onAnimationUpdate(), rather than relying on invalidate()?

Or, alternatively, is there a way to relinquish the UI thread during a long onLayout()?

Comment: is your code a part of some custom `View`? or `ViewGroup`? what do you want to draw inside `dispatchDraw`?

Comment: I am starting with a bitmap of the current screen-sized layout. I'd like the animation to zoom that and, when the new layout is rendered anmiate a fade-in. I may try other animation; I'm not sure what will look best.

Comment: have you read this: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/ ? i think your case is one of 4 last items in the list

Comment: I had skimmed through that. Took a second look. I think those are all useful examples but don't address the problem at hand, which is that onLayout() takes too long and is preventing the animation.

Comment: why `onLayout` takes too long? are you using a custom `ViewGroup`? what do you want to achieve actually? maybe post all your custom `View` code?

Comment: I have a custom list view with somewhat complicated list element layouts, plus some other surrounding views. Some of the things that take time are formatting dates and rendering images. Yes, it can be optimized, but even so, the layout will take to long for animation to work.